# Authenticating Domain - Custom DNS CName record Not Recognised

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, cname, namecheap

I own the domain abc.com purchased through NameCheap. I have set up a custom DNS redirecting it to my digital ocean droplet as below.

```
NAMESERVERS:
ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
ns3.digitalocean.com
```

This is working fine.

My email for @abc.com is provided by Google and this has been setup through corresponding A and MX records on Digital Ocean, and the email is working fine.

Now, I am attempting to authenticate this domain for both Mailchimp and firebase to send emails using my @abc.com email.

For Mailchimp, they need me to authenticate the domain using c-name records as below -

```
Mailchimp Instructions:
CNAME 1 : Name: k2._domainkey.abc.com, Value: dkim2.mcsv.net
CNAME 2: Name: k3._domainkey.abc.com, Value: dkim3.mcsv.net
```

On my digital ocean I set up the following CNAME records:

```
Type- Hostname - Value - TTL (seconds)  
CNAME- k2._domainkey.abc.com -  dkim3.mcsv.net - 43200  
CNAME-  k3._domainkey.abc.com - dkim2.mcsv.net - 43200
```

This is Not Working. I am getting the following message:

```
Uh oh, something went wrong.It looks like something didn't get copied and pasted correctly when you added the CNAME records to your domain. Delete or edit those records to try copying and pasting again.
```

I am having a similar problem with authenticating the domain for firebase to send emails from my @abc.com email, which leads me to believe that my setting up of CNAME record is incorrect.

Given my setup of the domain (Namecheap), custom DNS (digital ocean) and email (google) am I supposed to set up the c-name record differently? Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: If you include your real domain name, we can test your domain for you and know exactly what is wrong. Some DNS servers require a dot at the end of resource record names, others do not. For example, the name **k2._domainkey.abc.com** might actually resolve to **k2._domainkey.abc.com.abc.com**. Use a service like https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx to test your DNS resource records.

Comment: Hi, My domain is onmyfingertips.com. I used the mxtoolbox - the DNS record seems to be resolving correctly. However the authentication at Mailchimp and firebase end does not seem to be happening.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be occurring because of the custom DNS set-up on NameCheap redirecting it to digital ocean servers. I am given to understand from Mailchimp service provider that this means that some of the DNS records were not publicly visible. Hence the domain authentication failed.

I changed the set-up to a standard DNS set up on NameCheap, and created the CName records. The authentication then worked.